# Is there any way to integrate Mobile Web Browser and Android Application?

Tags: android, json, rest, spring-mvc

I am thinking of building an android app in which i use the mobile browser (google chrome) and open a localhost web server. Is there any way to integrate Mobile Web Browser and Android Application such that i need to process the data downloaded from my browser using my app. Data can be even a .txt file (but other formats too). Does my logic sounds reasonable or is there any existing implementation which is a kind of that..Any suggestions would help me a lot...Thanks (Pls ask for additional details if my question is unclear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [WebView](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/), which is just a poor man's stripped down version of a browser (without any of the  chrome). And you can use [Phone Gap](http://phonegap.com/) (now called Cordova), which is just a WebView with your own Javascript, css, and html on top (and that comes with extra code to integrate with Android and possibly other mobile OSes)

You could also call a Chrome Browser to load you a web page, but then you wouldn't have access to the content it had loaded (so you'd be better off just using a WebView or Phone Gap). Use the WebView alone if you prefer working in Java. Use Phone Gap if Javascript is more your thing (or if you want to port your solution to other mobile platforms).

Comment: A WebView is a layout component that can already render html, javascript, and css. It's just a skeleton component that you can build upon, make more functional, and load things into. Some people even use WebViews (written in Java) so that they can write the rest of their app in Javascript/CSS/HTML/Phone Gap http://phonegap.com/ . It's a convenient component to have even for just html. Writing your own html parser and renderer is not a trivial thing by any means. It's best to use what's already  pre-built.

Comment: I Tried Webview and it does open a stripped down version of my localhost web server in the app's main page itself. In my logic of web server it has user login and file download. So when i hit signin button in the Webview display of my webpage it directs me to internet (inbuilt browser of android which i couldn't uninstall. But i unistalled google chrome) like the regular file download which takes place in any browser. How to go ahead in integrating the file downloaded with my android app.

Comment: Use some of the boiler code that comes with Phone Gap. That will solve your problem of getting redirected to the Chrome Browser. Right now, I'm too tired to search for the relevant snippet of code that overrides that part of it, but it's in there for sure. As to the file download, it depends which you'd prefer. Do you prefer to work in Javascript, or in Java? In any case, you should also be able to find some Phone Gap code for authentication and downloading a file. Just make sure to add the keyword 'tutorial' when googling for those topics.

Comment: I have developed a Spring-Mvc web application already which runs in my machine. And I try to access it by opening http://machineip:portno/ from my mobile web browser (which is Webview now after u said). The login, signup & file download logic has already been taken care by web appln linking it with DB. I just want my Mobile app to open that web link, signin and download file at which i will try to get some of parameters of mobile and use it for my app. (just an outline). Does Webview  support processing JSON object / data?

Comment: WebView doesn't directly support processing json/data. There are various third party convenience libraries you can find that do however, if you just google around for one. What you're doing is a common enough problem, there are tons of tutorials on the subject.